# What is the perímeter of the triangle ABC?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I am froze in this question after some hours.

It's a homework (without a detailed solution in the book) that I am trying to do.

I am graduated in high school, but there is some years I didn't study these topics.

I am currently studing about cosin and sin law, and triangles similarity, and I think one of these tools would help to solve the problem, since it's a problem from the chapter of these subjects.

I've froze because $$ \frac{DB}{DA} = \frac{DB}{DC}$$ is resulting in a false equality.

See here:

$$
\frac{4}{x} = \frac{4}{x+6}
\\
\text{  }
\\
\text{which results in} 
\\
\text{  }
\\
4x = 4x + 24
\\
\text{  }
\\
\text{what led us to: }
0 = 24
$$

Is a clearly false equality, given this, I would like to know what I am doing wrong.
The book is: Fundamentos de Matemática, a Brazilian basic math book (In english can be called Mathematics Fundamentals)

Here is the link to the book in amazon: https://a.co/d/9HdJFCj

[image: Triangle]

Comment: For anyone which did down vote, tell me why, so I can improve question next time.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Also note that triangles ADB and BDC are similar triangles.

Comment: Alternatively, see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. Previously I shared the Image as a link because I don't have reputation to embed directly.

Comment: Anyway, next question I surely will follow the steps about: My education level, context, book name, and showing my work until the moment.

Comment: @user2661923 I've edited the content, now I think is better, but I would like your review, thanks.

And again, thank you for using your time to help me improving my questions.

Comment: Details still omitted, based on the protocol article that I referred to:  What tools led up to this problem?  That is, assuming that the problem composer intends that you are supposed to apply learned theory to solve the problem, what theorems, previously solved problems, or worked examples do you think *might* be relevant?  Then, once you edit your posting with a description of the tools that you regard as pertinent, you should then present a well organized, good faith effort to use the tools to solve the problem.  It doesn't matter whether you are successful.  ...see next comment

Comment: What counts is that you showed a serious effort to use the tools that you were given to try to attack the problem.

Comment: Will edit right now to improve it.

Comment: @user2661923 now I think I did right.

Comment: By one of Euclid's properties on right triangles, $x(x+6)=4^2$...

Comment: No, try again.  You are close, but you make an algebraic mistake.  **By the way**: once you show the work, you will inevitably identify the satisfying value(s) of $~x,~$ which will imply that the problem (from your perspective) will be trivial.  That is, if you had made the required effort in the first place, you would never have posted the problem.  Instead, you would have solved it on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your triangle is drawn in reasonably good proportion I give you

HINTS:

Use similar triangles

$$ DA \cdot DC = 4^2 \to \text {find x}$$
$$ x=2? ~\text {or } x=8 ?$$
Use Pythagoras thm to find $BA,BC..$

Comment: How do you got $$ DA \cdot DC = 4^2 $$ ? Pardon if I seem a bit dumb, I am a bit tired of this question

Comment: Similar triangles. $ \frac{DA}{DB} = \frac{DB}{DC} $.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. But, since DA is the base we call b, and DC is the equivalent base we call b'. and h is 4 for both.

Why isn't it: $$ \frac{DA \text{ or } b}{DB \text{ or } h} = \frac{DC \text{ or } b'}{DB \text{ or } h'} \text{ ?} \\$$

Is it why they are back to the each other?

Comment: Oh my gooooooooosh, now I understand.

ADB is uppppp and BDC is lying down, they are similar, but they have different rotations.

I have to rotate himmmmm.

Thank you @Narasimham

My ADHD didn't see it, thank you very much, omg.

Comment: Glad it helped. No ADHD, you recognized triangular similarity after rotation about D. Good luck !

Comment: I've posted the solution after your tip right above.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution after a very good tip of  @Narasimham, I may thank you for this.

Happens that I forgot to rotate the triangle to compare the similarity in the right way.

[image: Answer]